# Guice assistedinject already configured

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, assisted-inject

I have an issue with the AssistedInject. I followed the instructions on this link 
https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject
but when I run my application I get an error:

```
ERROR [2015-04-23 14:49:34,701] com.hubspot.dropwizard.guice.GuiceBundle: Exception occurred when creating Guice Injector - exiting
! com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
!
! 1) A binding to java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was already configured at com.demo.migrator.service.democlient.DemoAPIFactory.create().
!   at com.demo.migrator.service.democlient.DemoAPIFactory.create(DemoAPIFactory.java:1)
!   at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.initialize(FactoryProvider2.java:577)
!   at com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1.configure(FactoryModuleBuilder.java:335) (via modules: com.demo.migrator.MigrationModule -> com.google.inject.assistedinject.FactoryModuleBuilder$1)
```

Here is my module configuration :

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
    .implement(DemoAPI.class, DemoClient.class)
    .build(DemoAPIFactory.class));
```

Here is how my factory looks like:

```
 public interface DemoAPIFactory {
   DemoAPI create(String _apiKey, String _secretKey);
 }
```

The interface is declared as following:

```
public interface DemoAPI {
   //list of interface methods
}
```

And here is the implementation

```
 @Inject
public DemoClient(@Assisted String _apiKey, 
       @Assisted String _secretKey) {
    secretKey = _secretKey;
    apiKey = _apiKey;
    baseURL = "xxxxx";
    expirationWindow = 15;
    roundUpTime = 300;
    base64Encoder = new Base64();
    contentType = "application/json";
}
```

I am using dropwizard guice bundle.

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Hi! I know you've been around awhile but you haven't asked many questions. There isn't enough information here to answer your question; please read [ask]. Specifically, that line of your module configuration looks ok, but we need to see the **constructor for DemoClient.class** and the **DemoAPIFactory code**. Please [edit] them into your question.

Comment: Thank you durron, I have updated all the information.

Comment: Do you have `DemoApi` defined anywhere else? Such as `bind(DemoApi.class)`? Look everywhere in all your modules, you most certainly have it somewhere.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This is a common problem, the solution is documented in the javadoc:

> **Making parameter types distinct**
>
> The types of the factory method's parameters must be distinct. To use
>   multiple parameters of the same type, use a named @Assisted annotation
>   to disambiguate the parameters. The names must be applied to the
>   factory method's parameters:
>
> ```
>  public interface PaymentFactory {
>     Payment create(
>         @Assisted("startDate") Date startDate,
>         @Assisted("dueDate") Date dueDate,
>         Money amount);    }
> ```
>
> ...and to the concrete type's constructor parameters:
>
> ```
> public class RealPayment implements Payment {
>   @Inject
>   public RealPayment(
>      CreditService creditService,
>      AuthService authService,
>      @Assisted("startDate") Date startDate,
>      @Assisted("dueDate") Date dueDate,
>      @Assisted Money amount) {
>      ...
>   }    }
> ```

Comment: Thank you Jan. I had completely missed that part on the documentation. It really hepled

Comment: Thank you sir. That was spot on.