# A binding to java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was already configured at TesterFactory.create()

Tags: java, assisted-inject

```
import com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted;

public interface TesterFactory {
    TesterResource create(@Assisted String serviceName, @Assisted String serviceType);
}
```

My TesterResource class has 2 members:

```
@Inject
@Assisted
private String serviceName;

@Inject
@Assisted
private String serviceType;
```

However when I build the code I get an error  A binding to java.lang.String annotated with @com.google.inject.assistedinject.Assisted(value=) was already configured at TesterFactory.create(). If I keep @Assisted only for serviceName, I do not get this error.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824177/guice-assistedinject-already-configured

Answer (score 0):

Assisted give you the ability to name the value, `@Assisted(value="blah")`

Right now (whatever is looking for the injection) is looking for an empty string. As you have it, you are assigning to values (`serviceName` and `serviceType`) to an empty value, so you are trying to assign different values to the same binding.